# Multiple file upload (even folder)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, flash

I'm looking for an easy to use (free) "module" that can upload multiple files / folders.
It must:

- Support image files
- be user-friendly
- be customizable

It may be written in:

- RoR (Ruby On Rails)
- Java
- Flash

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here [http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails/) the article explains how to use Paperclip

Or you could try [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) , a Javascript & Flash solution for file uploads

Answer (score 1):

Uploading multiple files and folders in one go is not supported by HTML, which means that your options are Flash or a Java applet. Ruby on Rails isn't going to help you because it's a server-side framework that generates HTML.